# custom sub container views in UICollectionView not displayed in iOS UIAutomation logElementTree or Xcode UI Testing debugDescription

Tags: ios, accessibility, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation, xcode-ui-testing

The top level container view is a custom UICollectionView. I have added two custom container views on top up location. The hierarchy tree is like below

> custom UICollectionView
>
> |- custom UIView container => 1 ImageButton
>
> |- custom UIView container => 8 Buttons
>
> |- custom UICollectionCells

Voice Over could respond with these buttons correctly.

But when I tried to use `UIAutomation` with `target.logElementTree()`, the element tree only finds the UICollectioncell list under the cutom UICollectionView, It cannot find the custom subview container and their children.

Then I tried Xcode UI Testing, using `app.debugDescription`. The result still only contains UICollectionCells in the custom UICollectionView, without buttons.

How could I make them appear in the UIAutomation element tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally by using [Aspects](https://github.com/steipete/Aspects) with the custom collection category:

In custom collection category, override `+(void)load`:

- add aspect block to init the stong property `a`, which storing all `accessibilityElements` after execution `initWithFrame:collectionViewLayout:` or `initWithCoder:`
- add aspect block to add subview to property `a` after execution `addSubview:`

finally, implement [UIAccessibilityContainer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAccessibilityContainer_Protocol/) protocol methods using the property `a`

Tricky part:
use `objc_setAssociatedObject` and `objc_getAssociatedObject` to handle `a`